# Angular: Input radios not maintaining selection in custom component implemented with ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been trying to create a custom radio component using `ControlValueAccessor` in Angular.

In the main component I have a form and it has two form controls which is tied to the custom  radio component I created. In the initial load, both the custom radio components are selected, but as soon as I change value, only one of the custom radio maintains the selected state.

[image: initial load]

[image: After changing the value]

[Stackblitz minimal repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cgc7rw?file=src/app/radio.html)

There seems to be an issue which is causing this unusual behavior and I am unable to figure it out. I tried with both `ngModel` (with standalone option) & `FormControl` within the custom component implementing the `ControlValueAccessor`, but to no avail.

radio.html

```
<div>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let o of options; index as i; trackBy: trackByCode">
    <input
      type="radio"
      id="{{ inputName + '_' + o.code }}"
      [value]="o.code"
      [attr.name]="inputName"
      [formControl]="control"
      (blur)="onBlur($event)"
      (change)="onChange($event)"
    />
    <label for="{{ inputName + '_' + o.code }}"> {{ o.name }} </label>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

radio.component.ts

```
import { Component, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

import {
  ControlValueAccessor,
  FormControl,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
} from '@angular/forms';

const MY_RADIO_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => RadioComponent),
  multi: true,
};

@Component({
  selector: 'radio',
  templateUrl: './radio.html',
  providers: [MY_RADIO_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
})
export class RadioComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() inputName;
  @Input() options = [];

  control = new FormControl();
  private _onChange!: (_: any) => void;
  private _onTouched!: (_: any) => void;

  trackByCode(index: number, option: any) {
    return option.code;
  }

  writeValue(value: string): void {
    this.control.setValue(value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this._onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this._onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    isDisabled ? this.control.disable() : this.control.enable();
  }

  onChange($event: any) {
    this._onChange(this.control.value);
  }

  onBlur($event: any) {
    this._onTouched($event);
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
fruitOptions = [
    { name: 'Tomato', code: 'tomato' },
    { name: 'Apple', code: 'apple' },
    { name: 'Banana', code: 'banana' },
  ];
  vegOptions = [
    { name: 'Cabbage', code: 'cabbage' },
    { name: 'Potato', code: 'potato' },
    { name: 'Beans', code: 'beans' },
  ];

  form = this.fb.group({
    fruit: ['tomato', Validators.required],
    veg: ['cabbage', Validators.required],
  });
```

app.component.html

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <radio inputName="fruit" [options]="fruitOptions" formControlName="fruit"></radio>
  <radio inputName="veg" [options]="vegOptions" formControlName="veg"></radio>
</div>
<br />
<div>{{ form.value | json }}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In radio.html don't use [attr.name]="inputName" but use [name]="inputName" instead.

Essentially, right now is like you are not setting the name property, so from an HTML point of view all radio belongs to the same group.

This seems to be a known issue:
[angular github issue #24871](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24871)

Comment: Initially I had [name], but in html angular was changing it to ng-reflect-name="veg" and there was no name attrib in generated input element, thats why I had used attr.name.

Comment: And the known issue you posted is not applicable here, its for web components. If we need kebab case or something else, we need to alias @Input(), like `@Input('input-name') inputName: string`, but not necessary.

Comment: It was very late when I posted this question ~2AM, and before sleeping I found the issue, added answer.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** Angular needed both `[name]` and `[attr.name]`

Initially I had `[name]`, but in the markup generated by angular, there  was no name attribute. It was changing to `ng-reflect-name="veg"` and since there was no `name` attrib, html was not considering it as a group.

```
<input type="radio" ng-reflect-name="veg" ng-reflect-value="cabbage" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" id="veg_cabbage" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched">
```

Later, I found we need to `[attr.name]` to tell Angular to differentiate this from native attribute. This time the generated markup had `name` and looked good, but it still didn't work.

```
<input type="radio" ng-reflect-value="cabbage" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" id="veg_cabbage" name="veg" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

I tried few other methods and made it work by getting the list of radio inputs using `ViewChildren` and setting the `checked` property through `nativeElement`.

But the actual solution turned to be simpler, setting both `[name]` and `[attr.name]` on the input, one for angular and the other for the native html, finally did it.